# What are the numbering here for my model.summary()? I cannot understand clearly what the .summary() implies here

Tags: deep-learning, model

I know about the embedding layer, bidirectional LSTM and dense layers as well. However, I don't understand clearly that what are the numbering actually doing here? Is that for my several time iterations over the same layers??
So, my questions are:

1. What is the number 7 in **embedding_7**?
2. What is the number 13 and 14 in **bidirectional_13** and **bidirectional_14**?

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param # 
==========================================================================
embedding_7 (Embedding)      (None, 300, 8)            19307592 
bidirectional_13 (Bidirecti  (None, 300, 256)         141312    
onal)  
bidirectional_14 (Bidirecti  (None, 256)              395264    
onal)
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 9)                 2313      

=================================================================
Total params: 19,846,481
Trainable params: 19,846,481
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow / keras layers have a name property which has to be unique for graph generation. If you don't supply a (unique!) name with the 'name' keyword, tensorflow / keras will generate a name for you (the first term in the list, before the parentheses).

To make generated names unique, an incrementing number starting from 0 is appended. So 'dense_7' is the 8th Dense-layer the net has created in the graph.

Comment: So, why would I see 13, 14 in bidirectional as the embedding and dense are of 7 only? Here, they are being iterated similarly, right? If your answer is taken into account :)

Comment: Good question,  I can't definitely say why you don't see embedding_0, dense_0 and so on. Do you create other models (or iterations of your model) somewhere earlier in your code? I know that keras sometimes does not reset these layer IDs when creating new models.